# Use structureMap.autoMocking with objectFactory.BuildUp

Tags: c#, unit-testing, objectfactory, structuremap-automocking

My class is like:

```
public class BillingAccountBLService : IBillingAccountBLService
{
    [SetterProperty]
    public IContractService ContractService { get; set; }

    public BillingAccountBLService()
    {
        ObjectFactory.BuildUp(this);
    }
}
```

In my test:

```
[Test]
public void ContractDoesNotExist()
{
   var mocks = new RhinoAutoMocker<BillingAccountBLService>();
   var service = mocks.ClassUnderTest;
   ...
```

on this row exception thrown

> StructureMap.StructureMapConfigurationException : No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type..." (type of first injected service)

How should I fix this?

Comment: Try mocking your Interface instead of your implementation, not sure if that will work as I am not familiar with how RhinoAutoMocker works but with Moq I typically mock the interface.  I also am unsure what you are trying to test here.

Comment: @JCisar, I cant mock the interface "public class RhinoAutoMocker<T> : AutoMocker<T> where T : class" https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap/blob/master/src/StructureMap.AutoMocking/RhinoAutoMocker.cs
what i'm trying to test isn't rellevant.

Comment: I assume that `ObjectFactory` is StructureMap, if so the problem is you didn't register `BillingAccountBLService` in your IOC container.

Comment: I has this row - "For<IBillingAccountBLService>().Use<BillingAccountBLService>();" in my registry file.
it cant be the problem, because the class working OK, just the test not working

Comment: @user3202422 so you didn't call the registration method before `var mocks = new RhinoAutoMocker<BillingAccountBLService>();
   var service = mocks.ClassUnderTest;`....

Comment: it also cant be the problem, since this test work perfect before i tried automocking. it had in the beginning of it: 
`**public Mock<IContractService> MockContractService { get; set; }
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
        **MockContractService = new Mock<IContractService>();
        **ObjectFactory.Inject(MockContractService.Object);
}`
then i deleted this rows with **, and try using automocking, but didnt succeeded